# HERE maps isochrone request departure

Tags: gis, here-api

I'm following this example:

https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/routing/time-based-isoline-start-as-center

but it seems to always return a different result depending on when I call it. I would like to specify the departure time the isochrone is calculated at but I don't see any like in the [simple routing example](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/routing/route-from-a-to-b).

Can I specify this parameter or do I just have to make my program run at different times of day automatically (I'm proposing this solution just as a joke)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you get a different result depending on when you call the API is because the routing algorithm takes the traffic speed and incidents into account when calculating the route.

You can set a departure time in the request with the `departure` query parameter with a specific time as a value, or with the special value *now*:

> **departure**
>
> *Time when travel is expected to start. Traffic speed and incidents are taken into account when calculating the route. You can use `now` to specify the current time. It can be used only if parameter start is also used. Type: xs:dateTime.*
>
> `departure=2013-07-04T17:00:00+02`

Note: When the optional timezone offset is not specified, the departure value is assumed to be in local time.

Source: **[Calculate Isoline API Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-isoline.html)**

Comment: So for example I just need to add departure in the GET request like this? 

https://isoline.route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?mode=fastest%3Bcar&start=52.5160%2C13.3778&rangetype=time&range=300&departure=2013-07-04T17:00:00+02&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

It doesn't seem to work

Comment: I think this is because the `+` character in the timezone offset value has not been encoded in the url. You can see from the response that it was interpreted as a space. If you need the timezone and want to try directly from the url, replace the plus sign with `%2B` instead. Also, the documentation says if you omit the timezone, the time will be considered locally, in this case in the timezone of the start coordinates.

Comment: Maybe a helpful link https://gis-ops.github.io/reachability-analysis/ you could use the network tab in the browser tools and see what's going in in the GET request.